# Visual Basic 6.0 UML Diagram generator

Tags: vb6, uml

Are there any free UML diagram generator that could convert a VB6 source code into a UML diagram?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Basic Project Code to UML diagram tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191287/visual-basic-project-code-to-uml-diagram-tool)

Comment: The other question only mentions commercial and pay for single time use tools. Nothing free. And some of those products are no longer available. Definitely not a duplicate question, since this is asking for FREE UML diagram generator for VB6.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the built-in Visual Modeler mentioned by Deanna [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912161/use-case-and-activity-diagram-of-vb6-proj-tool)?

If you haven't tried it yet: Add-Ins menu in VB6, Add-in Manager.  Set Startup/Loaded for Visual Modeler Add-in and Visual Modeler Menus Add-in.   Then under the Add-Ins menu, you should see Visual Modeler ==> Reverse Engineering Wizard.

It was good enough to diagram classes in our (large) project.