# use case and activity diagram of VB6 proj tool

Tags: vb6, uml, tool-uml

project type is vb6.I have the source code.
is there any tool available which will generate the diagrams for the selected project...

Please reply soon.
I used Altova but that does not support vbp types...is there any other tool available ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Visual Studio 6.0 enterprise had Visual Modeller that could do almost UML

Comment: any online tool is there ?which will generate the diagrams from my project..

Comment: I doubt it for VB6. I use [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/) for manual creation as all the other tools seem to be geared around databases.

Comment: See these questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235067/visual-basic-6-0-uml-diagram-generator/2732648#2732648 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321448/bestpractice-approaches-for-reverse-engineering-vb6-code-with-out-knowledge-of-t and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191287/visual-basic-project-code-to-uml-diagram-tool and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367552/orm-mda-uml-tool-for-vb6

Comment: I'm struggling to see how *any* tool could create *use case* and *activity diagrams* from source code in *any* language. Those diagrams are high-level representations of the user's requirements, in user language.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Architect from [Sparx System](http://www.sparxsystems.com)s fully suppoprts reverse engineering and diagram creation of legacy vb6 code. You can find a [rundown of its code import options on the sparx systems website.](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/software_engineering/reverseengineersourcecode.html)

Looking into it deeper - Sparx Systems also have a list of the [code to UML stereotype conversions](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/software_engineering/visual_basic_conventions.html) it uses with the VB6 import process.